# Why i can't connect to mysql database in java?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I found this code in a tutorial but it isn't working when I debug it try the connection and then it isn't throw exception only go to the finally block without do any line of code under the DriverManager.getConnection().
Why? Anyone has an idea?

```
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://host/databasename";
            String user = "user";
            String password = "pass";


            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Message");

                if (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

            } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (rs != null) {
                        rs.close();
                    }
                    if (st != null) {
                        st.close();
                    }
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.close();
                    }

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
                    lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
                } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Logcat write this:
[Logcat Message](http://postimg.org/image/mghkuaoz7/)

Comment: "then it isn't throw exception" -- it must be. However, you have a completely random set of logging (some `e.printStackTrace()` and some `Logger.getLogger()`, neither of which are typical in Android), so perhaps you are not seeing specifically where it is being logged. You might wish to standardize on `android.util.Log` for your logging for the moment. Also note that Android does not ship with a MySQL JDBC driver. IMHO, Android apps should not be using JDBC, but instead should speak a Web service protocol to a Web service that you wrap around your MySQL database.

Comment: If android apps should not be using jdbc how can I communicate with MYSQL server?

Comment: As I wrote, they should speak a Web service protocol to a Web service that you wrap around your MySQL database. This is no different than any other Internet-connected scenario (e.g., Web browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `DriverManager.getConnection()` returns an object of type `Connection`, so there is no need to cast it. Same thing for `st = (Statement) con.createStatement();`

2) Unless you're running MySQL on a remote machine, you need to make sure you have MySQL installed on your local machine. If you decide to run MySQL on your local machine, you can connect to it with `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/{existing_db_name}";` given that everything else remains the same.

3) It seems like you're catching the same exception twice:

```
try{
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    ...
}catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
    lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
} catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As a result, your second catch block, the one that prints the exception message to `System.err`, never runs. Instead, you print the exception message to a `Logger`. This might be why you think no exception is being thrown, when in reality, an exception **is** being thrown.

4) Make sure you [download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) the JDBC driver for MySQL. Copy and paste it into the directory of your project.

Comment: 1) Eclipse not allow the connection and the statement without cast.
2) My MYSQL database is not in my local machine.
3) I delete one of the sql exception and nothing changed.

Comment: Make sure you're imports are correct (i.e. import java.sql.*;).

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted some catch block:

```
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://host:3306/databasename";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "pass";


    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Message");

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can you please specify what String url are you using? At this point, with these modifications I obviously get a **SQLException** with **No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://host/databasename**

Comment: String url = "jdbc:mysql://sql3.freesqldatabase.com/sql314318";

Comment: Have you put the jar of the driver in your /lib folder?